# Unit testing of GWT RequestFactory services without GWTTestCase

Tags: java, gwt, junit

Somewhere, I don't remember where, I spotted information, that starting from GWT 2.1.1 it is possible to test ReqeustFactory services without GWTTestCase. If this is true, please show me how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`RequestFactorySource`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/vm/RequestFactorySource.html) type can be used to instantiate `RequestFactory` instances in non-GWT runtimes.  The previously-mentioned InProcessRequestTransport is used by GWT's own `RequestFactoryJreSuite` tests to avoid the need to fire up an entire GWT runtime environment.

The `RequestFactorySource` type isn't limited to just testing.  If you implement your own `RequestTransport` (perhaps based on a `java.net.HttpUrlConnection` or Apache `HttpClient` library), you can write console apps, bulk-query apps, or health probers using your production RequestFactory endpoints.  This is a huge improvement over GWT`s old RPC system, which only supports GWT-based clients.

Comment: The RequestFactoryMagic type has been renamed to RequestFactorySource as of svn revision r9946.

Answer (score 5):

I found it myself browsing GWT's source code. The answer is hidden in `InProcessRequestTransport` javadoc:

https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/testing/InProcessRequestTransport.java

Comment: @HDave
The whole RequestFactory code was moved to com.google.web.bindery package, the link is fixed now

Comment: new link: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/./user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/testing/InProcessRequestTransport.java