# Use pojo as gwt RequestFactory proxy instead of interface

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is there any easy way to use a pojo as a request factory proxy and not an interface? The case is that I would like to reuse the actual value object as is without creating an interface describing it.

I do not that this can not be done out of the box. GWT fails to compile with an error regarding non getter/setter methods insite the "proxy" class.

Answer (score 1):

This not possible, by design.  See this [previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119867/when-should-i-use-requestfactory-vs-gwt-rpc/4926459#4926459).