# RPC 1.0 vs deRPC GWT-RPC

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm reading a book about GWT (Google Web Toolkit) where the author quote the differences between RPC 1.O and deRPC.

In my professionnal project, for RPC calls we are using :

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet

In the book, the authour precognizes the uses of :

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService.RpcService (which extends RemoteService)
com.google.gwt.rpc.server.RpcServlet (which extends AbstractRemoteServiceServlet)

However, both RpcService and RpcServlet are javadoc marked :

*"EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change. Do not use this in production code."*

So, basically, does someone uses RpcService and RpcServlet ? And what are the difference between them ?

See this link on StackOverflow for more details : [When should I use RequestFactory vs GWT-RPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119867/when-should-i-use-requestfactory-vs-gwt-rpc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GWT [official](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication) project page (at the bottom):

`This feature did not work out as planned, and the GWT team strongly discourages its use. Try the Request Factory feature when you have non-trivial server-domain objects.`

So it is better not to use deRPC.

Comment: Good, I didn't see this RequestFactory feature. It seems Nice !