# Implementing GWT RequestFactory service for non-entity requests

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, server-communication

I have the following Java servlet that performs what I call the "*Addition Service*":

```
public class AdditionService extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // The request will have 2 Integers inside its body that need to be
        // added together and returned in the response.
        Integer addend = extractAddendFromRequest(request);
        Integer augend = extractAugendFromRequest(request);

        Integer sum = addend + augend;

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(sum);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get GWT's RequestFactory to do the same thing (adding two numbers on the app server and returning the sum as a response) using a `ValueProxy` and `AdditionService`, and am running into a few issues.

Here's the `AdditionRequest` (client tier) which is a value object holding two Integers to be added:

```
// Please note the "tier" (client, shared, server) I have placed all of my Java classes in
// as you read through the code.
public class com.myapp.client.AdditionRequest {
    private Integer addend;
    private Integer augend;

    public AdditionRequest() {
        super();

        this.addend = 0;
        this.augend = 0;
    }

    // Getters & setters for addend/augend.
}
```

Next my proxy (client tier):

```
@ProxyFor(value=AdditionRequest.class)
public interface com.myapp.client.AdditionRequestProxy extends ValueProxy {
    public Integer getAddend();
    public Integer getAugend();
    public void setAddend(Integer a);
    public void setAugend(Integer a);
}
```

Next my service API (in the shared tier):

```
@Service(value=DefaultAdditionService.class)
public interface com.myapp.shared.AdditionService extends RequestContext {
    Request<Integer> sum(AdditionRequest request);
}
```

Next my request factory (shared tier):

```
public class com.myapp.shared.ServiceProvider implements RequestFactory {
    public AdditionService getAdditionService() {
        return new DefaultAdditionService();
    }

    // ... but since I'm implementing RequestFactory, there's about a dozen
    // other methods GWT is forcing me to implement: find, getEventBus, fire, etc.
    // Do I really need to implement all these?
}
```

Finally where the magic happens (server tier):

```
public class com.myapp.server.DefaultAdditionService implements AdditionService {
    @Override
    public Request<Integer> sum(AdditionRequest request) {
        Integer sum = request.getAddend() + request.getAugend();
        return sum;
    }

    // And because AdditionService extends RequestContext there's another bunch of
    // methods GWT is forcing me to implement here: append, create, isChanged, etc.
    // Do I really need to implement all these?
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is my "tier" strategy correct? Have I packaged all the types in the correct client/shared/server packages?

   - I don't think my setup is correct because `AdditionService` (in shared) references `DefaultAdditionService`, which is on the server, which it shouldn't be doing. Shared types should be able to live both on the client and the server, but not have dependencies on either...
2. Should `ServiceProvider` be a class that implements `RequestFactory`, or should it be an interface that **extends** it? If the latter, where do I define the `ServiceProvider` impl, and how do I link it back to all these other classes?
3. What about all these methods in `ServiceProvider` and `DefaultAdditionService`? Do I need to implement all 20+ of these core GWT methods? Or am I using the API incorrectly or not as simply as I could be using it?
4. Where does service locator factor in here? How?

Comment: Why are not using the standard GWT-RPC?

Comment: Thanks @Fedy2 - well I'll be using RF for all of my other CRUD/entity-oriented services, which is what RF is mainly used for. But RF also offers non-entity server communication (which is what I need here, in this question) and I'd like to stay consistent with the rest of my architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use RF as a simple RPC mechanism [*] you can (and you are right: only `ValueProxy`s), but you need something more: `ServiceLocator`s (i.e., GWT 2.1.1).

With `ServiceLocator` you can simply put your service implementation (like your servlet) into a real service instance, instead into an *entity object* (as you will use only `ValueProxy`s, with no static `getXyz()` methods) as required by the RF protocol. Note the existence also of `Locator`s, used to externalize all those methods from your server-side entities: not needed if you use `ValueProxy` everywhere.

A `ServiceLocator` looks something like (taken from [official docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#locators)):

```
public class DefaultAdditionServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
  @Override
  public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
      return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

You need to annotate your `DefaultAdditionService` also with a locator param, so RF knows on what to rely when it comes to dispatch your request to your service. Something like:

```
@Service(value = DefaultAdditionService.class, locator = DefaultAdditionServiceLocator.class)
public interface com.myapp.shared.AdditionService extends RequestContext {
  // Note here, you need to use the proxy type of your AdditionRequest.
  Request<Integer> sum(AdditionRequestProxy request);
}
```

Your service will then be the simplest possible thing on Earth (no need to extend/implement anything RF-related):

```
public class com.myapp.server.DefaultAdditionService {
  // The server-side AdditionRequest type.
  public Integer sum(AdditionRequest request) {
    Integer sum = request.getAddend() + request.getAugend();
    return sum;
  }
}
```

If you mispell `sum()` or you do not implement a method declared in your `RequestContext` you will get an error.

To instantiate `RequestContext`s you need to *extend* the `RequestFactory` interface, with a public factory method for `com.myapp.shared.AdditionService`. Something like:

```
public interface AdditionServiceRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
  public com.myapp.shared.AdditionService createAdditionServiceRequestContext();
}
```

All your client *calls* will start from this. See the docs, if not already.

Now, RF works by totally separating the objects your want to pass from client (using `EntityProxy` and `ValueProxy`) and server (the *real* objects, either `Entity` values or simple `DTO` classes). You will use proxy types (i.e., interfaces whom implementations are automatically generated) everywhere in client/shared tier, and you use the relative domain object (the one referenced with `@ProxyFor`) only on server side. RF will take care of the rest. So your `AdditionRequest` will be on your server side, while `AdditionRequestProxy` will be on your client side (see the note in the `RequestContext`). Also note that, if you simply use primitive/boxed types as your `RequestContext` params or return types, you will not even need to create `ValueProxy`s at all, as they are default [transportable](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable).

The last bit you need, is to wire the `RequestFactoryServlet` on your `web.xml`. See the [docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#wiring) here. Note that you can extend it if you want to, say, play around with custom `ExceptionHandler`s or `ServiceLayerDecorator`s, but you don't need to.

Speaking about where to put everything:

- `Locator`s, `ServiceLocator`s, service instances, domain objects, and `RequestFactoryServlet` extensions, will be on your server-side;
- The `RequestContext`, `RequestFactory` extensions and all your proxy types will be on the shared-side;
- client side will initialize the `RequestFactory` extension and use it to obtain the factory instance for your service requests.

All in all... to create a simple RPC mechanism with RF, just:

- create your service along with `ServiceLocator`;
- create a `RequestContext` for your requests (annotated with service and locator values);
- create a `RequestFactory` extension to return your `RequestContext`;
- if you want to use more than primitive types in your `RequestContext` (like simple `DTO`s), just create client proxy interfaces for them, annotated with `@ProxyFor`, and remember where to use each type;
- wire everything.

Much like that. Ok, I wrote too much and probably forgot something :)

For reference, see:

- [Official RF documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html);
- Thomas Broyer's articles [[1]](http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-211-requestfactory/), [[2]](http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-211-requestfactory-part-ii/);
- [RF vs GWT-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119867/when-should-i-use-requestfactory-vs-gwt-rpc) from the RF author point of view.

[*]: In this approach you shift your logic from *data-oriented* to *service-oriented* app. You give up using `Entity`s, `ID`s, `version`s and, of course, all the complex diff logic between client and server, when it comes to `CRUD` operations.

Comment: Thank you, @Andrea Boscolo! (+1 and I wish I could upvote your answer 10 more times!). Fantastic answer, and it really made things clearer for me. However I do have just one tiny followup question for you:

Comment: If `RequestContext`s (like my `AdditionService`) are packaged inside the shared-tier, which will be present on both the client- and server-tiers, then how is it "legal" for its `@Service` annotation to reference a server-tier class like `DefaultAdditionService`? I would think that when GWT goes to cross-compile the shared-tier source code, that it would complain about the existence of a type packaged in `com.myapp.server.*`. Ideas? Thanks again for such an awesome answer!

Comment: GWT won't complain for classes referenced only from annotations; but if you want separate projects/JARs then you'll have a packaging issue (client depends on shared which depends on server). You can cut the "shared depends on server" dependency by using `@ServiceName` and `@ProxyForName` instead of `@Service` and `@ProxyFor`. Also, note that you can use `int` instead of `Integer` in your "request object". You could also pass two arguments of type `Integer` or `int` to the `sum` method, rather than a "request object".

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBroyer (+1) - I'll take all that into consideration. Actually one more thing that cropped up while implementing Andrea's suggestions is the presence of this generic `Request` object as the `DefaultAdditionService#sum`'s return value. What if my service was returning something other than a primitived/boxed type? ...

Comment: What if my service was returning a `Request<Widget>` instead of a `Request<Integer>`? Since `Request` is an interface, do I really need to implement my own `Request` impl (and all the methods that go with it - `with`, `to`, `fire`, etc.) or is there an easier way to simply return a `Widget`? Thanks again to anyone who can help me!!!

Comment: Ahh nevermind I see your edit to his answer and that explains everything. Thanks!

Comment: I knew I forgot something... Thanks for the edit @ThomasBroyer. Glad to help.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't comment here about it because you were returning an `Integer` value, so it was clearly an oversight.

Comment: Amount of work required by request factory even for simple tasks is ridiculous. I have yet to see use case where just RPC would not be better.